Treatment effect estimation for policy change in time series
I have time series data and want to estimate the impact of a policy change on an outcome. The policy comes into effect at some point and remains active for the rest of the sample period. So I only have untreated units before the policy change and treated units after.
Is there any commonly used method to estimate the causal effect?

I would look into the regression discontinuity design in general, but for the time series case this corresponds to the interrupted time series design. There is an interesting and simple tutorial paper for R software (here)
In these ppt both are presented and described in nice way: here
